# Rails controller variable (@s3_direct_post) into Application.js.erb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am attempting to get a variable called @s3_direct_post from my controller into Application.js.erb; here is my controller action:

```
def new
  unix_ts = Time.now().to_i.to_s
  @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "#{unix_ts}_${filename}",
                                             success_action_status: 201,
                                             acl: :public_read)
  @video = Video.new({title: "Title with hashtags"})
end
```

Application.js.erb has two lines that reference @s3_direct_post:

```
url: '<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>',
```

and

```
formData: '<%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>'
```

But these are not being processed by erb. I get a 400 Bad Request error with the following requested URL message:

```
http://subdomain.mysite.com:3000/videos/%3C%=%20@s3_direct_post.url%20%%3E
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly transfer this value into Application.js.erb so it populates with the value of the instance variable?

P.S. If I remove the quotes from each of these erb strings, I get the error message saying that the method 'url' does not exist because @s3_direct_post is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hidden_field_tag` in `new.html.erb` as the following:

```
hidden_field_tag 's3_direct_post_url', '#{@s3_direct_post.url}'
```

And then get this value from application.html.erb using jquery as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = $('#s3_direct_post_url').val();
})
```